# How to pass data from database to html using jinja2, Flask and mongodb and while loop

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I am confused about passing data from database (mongodb) to html.

I have python code in "**init**.py" that queries database using while logic - see below code snippet:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

from flask import Flask, render_template

@app.route("/snapshot")

def pymongo_query():
   db=client.collection
   months=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
   while months:
      mon=months.pop()
      query=list(db.collection.find({args}))
      query=query[0]
      month=query['month']
      item_1=query['item_1']
      item_2=query['item_2']
```

What this codes does is it goes through each month represented by number in list and queries database for the respective month. I use while loop to go over months. In Python I would use print at the end of loop to output result.

How do I output data into html using jinja2? I was wondering if I need to have while logic in jinja or keep it as I have it right now in **init**.py file above.

Answer (score 7):

I hope this will help you.

You can pass the arguments item_1,item_2,month etc. to HTMLfile by adding these to a list or dictionary.

```
list=[month,item_1,item_2]
or 
list=[]

list.append(month)
list.append(item_1)
list.append(item_2)
```

and pass it as

```
@app.route('/')
def something():
    return render_template("abc.html",my_list=list)
```

Now for using this in html (using jinja2)
add some code like:

```
<ul>
    {% for n in my_list %}
    <li>{{n}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

in your abc.html file.
Now run the **init**.py file again and check output.

Answer (score 3):

[Like the tutorial in the Flask docs demonstrates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/), you return a call to `render_template`, passing the information that the template needs to the call.  All application and complex logic should stay out of the template.  Assuming you've made a 'snapshot.html' template in the 'templates' folder, and assuming you do something to collect `item_1` and `item_2` in the while loop to a collection `items`:

```
return render_template('snapshot.html', items=items)
```